# What's the meaning of "bring a human face to"?

Tags: meaning

The global financial crisis had brought a human face to structural wealth and income inequality in Anglo-American countries.

Comment: Looks like a variant on [put a human face on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/human%20face) but not sure if this is a common version of it.

Comment: It means that people instead of numbers figured in news reports. It can also mean finding someone to blame.

Answer (score 2):

This an idiomatic expression, similar to others where *put* is used instead of *bring*:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20a%20human%20face%20on)
>
> put a human face on: idiom
> Definition of put a human face on:
> to make (something) more appealing, easier to understand, or easier to care about by connecting it to an actual person
> *The author puts a human face on the disease by interviewing people who have it.*

We may understand that the global financial crisis has led to our seeing specific examples of people who have been affected by structural (built-in, institutionalised) inequality, rather than our merely knowing the generality of inequality.

For a similar example, where rapportage brings a human face to the impersonal statistics of misfortune, see:

> [Dispatches from the frontiers of humanity](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Dispatches_from_the_Frontlines_of_Humani/Mtl9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22put+a+human+face%22&pg=PR11&printsec=frontcover)
>
> *By telling these peopleГs stories, Bośtjan helps put a human face on the suffering that is too often viewed statistically and quantitatively. The lives he captures with his pen are victims of forces beyond their control*